# Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields display content if no option

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have some options to show different addresses in the footer depending on whether the user selects a page ID from a post object field. I have it working so that if the user selects post object = 'Music' it displays the 'Music' address etc but what I cant get to work is if no options have been selected to then just show a default address.

this is what I have so far:

```
<?php if( have_rows('footer_details', 'option') ): ?>
    <?php while( have_rows('footer_details', 'option') ): the_row(); ?> 
        <?php
            $post_object = get_sub_field('company', 'option');
        ?>
        <?php
            if ( is_page($post_object) ) {  ?>
            <div class="company-footer">
                <?php echo get_sub_field('address', 'option'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php } 
        ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<p><?php echo get_field('footer_address', 'option'); ?></p>
```

Comment: And what is the default address? Is that stored somewhere? How can we retrieve it?

Comment: The default address is just an ACF option called footer_address, it's not in the repeater field.

Comment: Understood, but you've asked us to help you show the default address, but _not_ shown us how to get / display the default address.  So by definition any answer you get will be incomplete.

Comment: I've edited my original question with the default footer address field. But this shows on every page even when i've added footers from the repeater field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of playing about I managed to solve it

```
<?php // load footer address outside of repeater

        $exists = false; //initialize the field to false;
        $default = get_field('footer_address', 'option');
        if( have_rows('footer_details', 'option') ):
          while( have_rows('footer_details', 'option') ): 
            the_row(); // moved the_row to it's own line for clarity
            $post_object = get_sub_field('company', 'option');
              if ( is_page($post_object) ) { 
                // load the address custom field into a variable named $address
                $exists = true; //set the value to true;
                $address = get_sub_field('address', 'option');
                // check if the $address variable is empty
              if ( ! $address ) {
                // if it is empty, load the default into the $address variable
                $address = $default;
              } 
        ?>

        <div class="company-footer">
          <?php 
            echo $address; // output the $address variable, which contains either the address or the default address
            echo get_sub_field('contact','option'); 
          ?>
        </div>

      <?php } 

        endwhile;
        endif;
        // evalute if it existed
        if($exists==false){ ?> 
        <div class="company-footer">
          <?php echo 'use the default footer'; ?>
        </div>
      <?php }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is *check* if the `address` field is set, and if not, then display the `default` address.

One way to do that is like below - I've loaded the address into a variable, and if the variable is "empty", then it assigns the default address to the variable.

NOTE:
In the code below, I've done two things:
I've removed much of the opening / closing PHP tags.  Those aren't necessary except for when transitioning from PHP to HTML, and make the code far more "noisy" and difficult to read.

I've added comments to explain what I'm doing.  You can remove these comments safely, if you want.

```
<?php // load footer address outside of repeater
      $default = get_field('footer_address', 'option');
      if( have_rows('footer_details', 'option') ):
          // removed closing / opening PHP tags for simplicity
          while( have_rows('footer_details', 'option') ): 
              // moved the_row to it's own line for clarity
              the_row();
              $post_object = get_sub_field('company', 'option');
              if ( is_page($post_object) ) { 
                  // load the address custom field into a variable named $address
                  $address = get_sub_field('address', 'option');
                  // check if the $address variable is empty
                  if ( ! $address ) {
                      // if it is empty, load the default into the $address variable
                      $address = $default;
                  } ?>
                  <div class="company-footer">
                      <?php // output the $address variable, which contains either the address or the default address
                            echo $address; ?>
                    </div>
            <?php } 
          endwhile;
       endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response, the footer_address(default address) is not showing on the homepage. does the footer_address field have to be in the repeater? the other footers within the repeater work fine on the selected pages.

Comment: Check the edit I just made.  Adjusted to load the default address outside the footer.

Comment: Thankyou, but again default footer does not show...you can see here http://foley13.webfactional.com/sky/home/

Comment: This is why I asked for you to show how we are supposed to display the default footer.  It's absolutely impossible for me to guess how to get your default footer from the system and display it - so, can you please post the code that _works_ to display your default footer?

Comment: If I just have <?php echo get_field('footer_address', 'option'); ?> this displays the default site footer on every page.